# asp-net web api serialized nested List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the api method that returns a Products  list: `getAllProduct()` returns filled list including:

```
List<Product> dependProduct
```

but the client receives an empty `dependProduct`.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public List<Product> dependProduct = new List<Product>();

}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("~/Shop/Product")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Product>))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
        var data = getAllProduct(); //  has dependProduct 
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}

private List<Product> getAllProduct()
{
  return context.Products.ToList();
}
```

Client:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/Shop/Product", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<List<Product>>(request);
return response.Data;  // has not dependProduct  why?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `dependProduct` declared as field rather than a property.
Try change Product to

```
public class Product
{
   public Product()
   {
      dependProduct = new List<Product>();
   }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public List<Product> dependProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a few hours